# Why can't my linux system find my home directory when logging in to the shell?

Tags: directory

I recently formatted the home partition on my server and manually created some of the users' directory to it. Since there were too many users on the system, I only created the users directory that are really needed.

But when I opened the terminal, the current directory shows as `/`, not `~`, meaning that the shell did not find my home path. But when I type `cd ~`, it goes straight to my home directory. And all the files are there. So the home partition is working and it's mounted to home as it should be, but the shell doesn't seem to find the home directory.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "the shell" - which shell? When creating the home directories, did you set the owners and permissions correctly?

Comment: The shell is bash. And yes, I set the owners and permissions as it should be. drwx------

Comment: all mine are `drwxr-xr-x` - so "should be" seems to be your opinion :p

Comment: It still doesn't work even if I set it as that

Comment: How do you open the shell?

Comment: "_But when I opened the terminal, the current directory shows as /, not ~, meaning that the shell did not find my home path_" - not necessarily. It only means you're in the root of the filesystem. If you run `getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6` does the resulting directory actually exist? Is it what you expect for your own home directory?

Comment: The shell starts in the directory it's parent (recursively) is in, so when the shell starts in `/`, it just means that the parent (again - recursively) is in `/`. If it used to work the easiest way to get everything (under your control + that doesn't change it themselves) to run from `~` is probably to reboot.

Comment: I guess I did not made myself clear. When logging in, It shows this message and goes to root(/) directory - "No home directory, logging in with HOME=/". But when I type "cd ~", it goes to my home directory with no problems. I've already restarted the system multiple times, and it is still the same.